# Discrete derivative condition for martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, martingales

For a simple symmetric random walk $S_n$, the process $f(S_n)$ is a martingale if and only if
$$D^2 f = f(x+1) - 2f(x) + f(x-1) = 0.$$
Where this condition comes from I have no idea. I have never seen this anywhere and cannot find it anywhere. That being said, I need to find a condition for some function $f(n, S_n)$ using this fact and then prove that $Y_n = \rho ^ {-n} e^{S_n}$ is a martingale where
$$\rho = \frac{e + e^{-1}}{2}.$$

Now, I have been looking at this problem for days and have no idea how to do it. I think we can write $f(n,S_n)$ as
$$f(n, S_n) = g(n)f(S_n).$$ Then we have that $g(n) D^2 f = 0$, so $g(n)$ can be anything at all. Obviously this is not true.

I truly have no idea. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried writing $\mathbb{E}[f(S_n) \mid S_{n-1}]$ explicitly?

Comment: @E-A My thought was that I only had to use the $D^2f$ thing because that is what was given. How would I do it with the expected value?

Comment: That is where the $D^2f = 0$ thing comes from. You can use the same logic to deduce the condition for $f(n, S_n)$ to satisfy.

Comment: @E-A If you wouldn't mind, or have time to, write more detail in the answer section I will give you an upvote and a green check. If not that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The $D^2f = 0$ condition can be rewritten as $f(x) = \frac 12 (f(x+1)+f(x-1))$.  We compute \begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[f(S_{n+1})|S_n] = \mathbb{E}[f(S_n + X_n) | S_n] = \frac 12 f(S_n + 1) + \frac 12 f(S_n-1),
\end{align*}
so we can see that the martingale condition $\mathbb{E}[f(S_{n+1})|S_n] = f(S_n)$ is equivalent to the $D^2f=0$ condition.

Do you see how to apply a similar method to find a condition for $f(n,S_n)$ to be a martingale?

Comment: I understand what you have written, but the second variable $n$ in the function is confusing me still.

Comment: @MathIsLife12 What would it mean for $f(n,S_n)$ to be a martingale?

Comment: Would I just put $n+1$ in the function?

Comment: @MathIsLife12 Sort of... how do you mean?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} f(n+1, S_n+1) + ...$ But this still is confusing me.

Comment: @MathIsLife12 Yes, that's right.  Which part is still confusing?

Comment: Because then you would have $\frac{1}{2} \rho ^ {- (n+1)} e^{x+1}  + ...$ and this does not simplify to anything meaningful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130516/discussion-between-user6247850-and-mathislife12).